# How to Combine two multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on dynamic form section with a felicity to add repeated fields, for serializing this, i want a combined array of two or more arrays, now a testing with two arrays and I combined these two like this,

```
$array1 =   Array
(
    [0] => Collect Invoices
    [1439797510547] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bank Name
        [1] => Invoices
    )

    [1] => Comment
);
$array2 =   Array
(
    [0] => repeatField
    [1439797510547] => Array
    (
        [0] => selectBanks
        [1] => text
    )

    [1] => textarea
);
$mixedArray =   array_combine($array1,$array2);

/* Result is like this */
Array
(
    [Collect Invoices] => repeatField
    [Array] => Array
    (
        [0] => selectBanks
        [1] => text
    )

    [Comment] => textarea
)
```

But I want an answer like this

```
Array
(
   [Collect Invices] => repeatField
   [1439797510547] => Array
   (
       [Bank Name] => selectBanks
       [Invoices] => text
   )

   [Comment] => textarea
)
```

Can anyone help me, please..thanks in advance

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: There is no magic what you want. You need to loop through and combine/merge whats needed to be.

Comment: Does `Bank Name`, `Invoices`, `Comment` are constant name fields? Does it has any direct link with it's values from other array?

Comment: Hi Justin, those are not constant, that is the label of the fields it will be any thing. [Bank Name] => selectBanks in this case Bank Name is the field and selectBanks is the type of field, these are related

Comment: Hi Hussain, there could be more arrays, can you please show me that how to loop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go mate:

```
$array1 = array(
            0 => 'Collect Invoices',
            1439797510547 => array(
                0 => 'Bank Name',
                1 => 'Invoices'
            ),
            1 => 'Comment'
        );
        $array2 = array
            (
            0 => 'repeatField',
            1439797510547 => array
                (
                0 => 'selectBanks',
                1 => 'text'
            ),
            1 => 'textarea'
        );


        $result_array = array();

        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $result_array[$value] = $array2[$key];
            }

            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $inner_key => $inner_value) {
                    $result_array[$key][$inner_value] = $array2[$key][$inner_key];
                }
            }
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result_array);
        echo "</pre>";
```

result is:

```
Array
(
    [Collect Invoices] => repeatField
    [983466387] => Array
        (
            [Bank Name] => selectBanks
            [Invoices] => text
        )

    [Comment] => textarea
)
```